# Adding parameter to $emit in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to emit a certain value from a child element to its parent.
In vue2 I have the folowwing code that works :

Child.vue :

```
 this.$emit('getValue', value);
```

Parent.vue

```
<Child @getValue="parseValue('someparameter', ...arguments)" />

parseValue(param, val){
// some code
}
```

And val in the methode `parseValue` always returned the correct value that is emited from the child.
But this doesn't work when we upgraded to Vue3. Now `val` is just a promise and I can't get the value out of it.

What should I do to get the value like we used to with Vue2 ?

Comment: `@getValue="parseValue('someparameter', ...$event)"` https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers

Comment: I vuejs3 emits declaration is updated see details https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#declaring-emitted-events. I believe you have followed vue3 migrations if not see https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/emits-option.html#emits-option

Comment: "val is just a promise" - it's unknown what this has to do with promises, they aren't normally involved in events, could be something that you didn't show.

Comment: Thanks all, I had to write ```@getValue="parseValue('someparameter'```, $event)" for it to work.